# Usual half day rate? 

Tags: rate, standard

I see gear rental places charge 75% of the day rate for half a day. And at restaurants, half a pasta dish is also around 75%. How about post-production or location recording?

For some reason, I have two half days this week and I'm wondering what the norm is? 75% of daily rate seem correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@andrew-spitz

Hey Andrew,

Ja that seems about right. In my little experience, a half day of location recording is always more than half a day, what with travel, set-up and breakdown time when going onto set. But I always charge 2/3 or 66.6666...% of a full day for a 'half-day'.(Maybe I should up my half-day rate to 75%?)

I'm trying to break into the sound design world now, and here the situation becomes more murky. How do I charge? Per hour? Per day? Flat rate on a task for task basis? Don't really know yet? I've tried talking to my lady( a freelance photographer) about it and we never seem to reach a point, as she has the same difficulty.
What do you think a good model for post is? Let's say doing sound design on a 20 second channel ident, for instance?
Sorry about the 'question-for-question' thing...

Kurt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 2/3 might be better actually. Your question is a good one, maybe you should post a brand new question about it, it will keep things more concise and others will be able to give great answers. Also, the @username is for comments, no need to put it in the question. 